# Unable to Initialize 2D Array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I have declared a 2D global array variable like so:

```
int grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

then in `main` I've to initialize it with hard-coded values:

```
grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 1, 4},
                                ....
                                {1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5}
                                };
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS    9
#define COLUMNS 9

/* Global variable. */
int grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

int main() 
{
   /* Initialze the 2D array. */
   grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 1, 4},
                                   ....
                                   {1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5}
                                  };

   return 0;
}
```

But when I try compiling the source code, GCC gives the following error:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:45:34: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
 grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 1, 4},
                                ^
```

I'm not sure why GCC is not recognizing `grid_2d_array` as a global variable.

The problem goes away if I redeclare the aforementioned variable in `main`.

I'm running GCC version: `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)`

Comment: Please provide a proper minimal example of this that others can try to compile. Now it's unclear where the definition is and if something else affects the problem.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your array and its nested arrays.

Comment: `grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS] =` specifies an element (which does not exist) of the array.  Try removing the `[ROWS][COLUMNS]` and just `use grid_2d_array = { /*your stuff goes here*/};`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use a `std::array<std::array<int>>` ?

Comment: @tobi303 Good question.  Is this C or C++ (it can't be both)?

Comment: @mike-of-sst It has to be C.

Comment: @JCM yes, if it has c-style arrays it has to be C ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C and C++ arrays can be initialized only as a part of the definition statement:

```
int grid_2d_array[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 1, 4},
                                    ....
                                    {1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5}
                                   };
```

Assignment of multiple values into an array is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to FireAphis's answer, if you are under C99 you can initialize a pointer to array of `int`s (not a 2D array) outside his definition using [compound literals](http://www.9wy.net/onlinebook/CPrimerPlus5/ch10lev1sec9.html):

```
int (*grid_2d_array)[COLUMNS]; /* Pointer to array of n int's */
```

in main:

```
grid_2d_array = (int [ROWS][COLUMNS]){
    {5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 6, 1, 4},
    {1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5}
};
```